# Django adding placeholder text for PasswordChangeView?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

A user can change their password on my change password page:

```
<form class="password-change-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{ form }}
    </div>
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Change password">
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
   path(
        'accounts/password_change/',
        auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='account/password_change_form.html'),
        name='password_change'
    ),
```

## The problem

PasswordChangeView [uses PasswordChangeForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) by default.

I would like to add placeholder text to this form i.e. Old password placeholder text: 'Enter your old password'.

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override **any class attribute** in the parameters to `as_view()`. So the same way you specify `template_name='account/password_change.html'` you can add `form_class=MyPasswordChangeForm`.

Just subclass `PasswordChangeForm` with your `MyPasswordChangeForm` and make any changes you need.

The class attributes of the `PasswordChangeView` are: `template_name`, `form_class`, `title` and `success_url` + the class attributes of `FormView` and those of `PasswordContextMixin`.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Within the MyPasswordChangeForm how would I add placeholder text? Currently I'm trying:                                                                                           class MyPasswordChangePasswordForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))    but to no avail

Comment: The fields of `PasswordChangeForm` are `old_password`, `new_password1` and `new_password2`.

Comment: oops my bad, I tried that before but had a typo! Thank you!